# Is there any way to add a description to an image using joomla! modal squeezebox?

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools, modal-dialog, squeezebox

I am using the Joomla modal window squeezebox. I wish to be able to add some text below the image popup, like on www.pathgate.org images.

Is there any way I can add this when calling up the modal window in the article?

E.g. Click here for

I was thinking there might be something like: description: 'lorem ipsum doler sit amet'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

`<a class="modal" href="images/powered_by.png" title="text" rel="{handler:'img_ext'}">test</a>`

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
  SqueezeBox.handlers.img_ext = function(elm) {
    var url = elm.href;
    this.image = new Image();
    var events = {
       loaded: function() {
       var win = {x: window.getWidth() - this.options.marginImage.x, y: window.getHeight() - this.options.marginImage.y};
       var size = {x: this.image.width, y: this.image.height};
       for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        if (size.x > win.x) {
          size.y *= win.x / size.x;
          size.x = win.x;
        } else if (size.y > win.y) {
        size.x *= win.y / size.y;
        size.y = win.y;
       }
    size = {x: parseInt(size.x), y: parseInt(size.y)};
    if (window.webkit419) this.image = new Element('img', {'src': this.image.src});
    else $(this.image);
    this.image.setProperties({
        'width': size.x,
        'height': size.y});
    size.y += 50;
    var title = new Element('div',{text:elm.title});
    var wrapper = new Element('div');
    wrapper.adopt([this.image,title]);
    this.applyContent(wrapper, size);
    }.bind(this),
    failed: this.onError.bind(this)
    };
    (function() {
       this.src = url;
    }).delay(10, this.image);
    this.image.onload = events.loaded;
    this.image.onerror = this.image.onabort = events.failed;
    };
SqueezeBox.parsers.img_ext=function(preset) {
return (preset || this.url.test(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/i)) ? $(this.element) : false;
};
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would that just be a case of adding the handler to the javascript? I don't know javascript, but if it was a simple line of code, I would be comfortable to add it. Do you know how I might add that self handler? Thank you

Comment: wow - thank you so much! I need to learn javascript though. I added that code to the ucompressed modal js file (at the bottom?) and then tried to call it up the way suggested but it didn't work. I'm grateful for your help and don't want to ask too much, but if you could give any pointers on what to do next, they would be greatly appreciated - or if you know of any good resources that can help me in this

Comment: Thanks VampiRUS for your help.I've ended up using the Yootheme Widgetkit for ease of use for the now.